# Lenovo Thinkpad w520 Wireless Drivers Not Working

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, lenovo, intel-wireless

I've run into a strange issue while trying to get Ubuntu 16.04 working on my laptop.  I am currently duel booting with Windows 10 on another partition, and during the installation process I *was* able to connect to WiFi during the connection step of setup.  However, upon booting into Ubuntu upon completion, wireless does not appear under the network manager anymore, only the Ethernet card does.

I've done a bunch of searching the past few hours and haven't came up with anything useful.  I've noticed that if I run:

```
lshw -c network
```

my WiFi Network Controller shows up as unclaimed (Intel Centrino Ultimate-n 6300), which should be supported by iwlwifi (which I'm pretty sure I had already, but I also downloaded the firmware for it and put it in /lib/firmware).    Modprobe iwlwifi or any variant hasn't worked either.  iwconfig just lists no wireless extensions.

Any thoughts as to things I can do to try to fix this?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try disabling Secure Boot at UEFI settings.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I actually don't have UEFI, and there doesn't appear to be an option for that in BIOS.

Comment: You may have installed both in Legacy mode but your notebook does have UEFI: http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/uefi-legacy-boot-options-w520.575680/ . Granted, if installed in Legacy, secure boot isn't applicable but otherwise please check again and disable it.

Comment: Ah okay, well I just did some searching and it appears that the version of UEFI I have does not support Secure Boot (at least according to someone in this thread:  https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-P-and-W-Series-Mobile/Debugging-W520-UEFI-boot/td-p/1273695)  Explains why I can't find an option to disable it in setup.  I also noticed this when trying something else before, Windows wouldn't allow me to enter UEFI advanced settings (http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/4/SLN143038/access-uefi--bios--system-setup-from-windows?lang=EN), the button for it didn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for what it's worth, all I had to do was use the older kernel and it was able to auto-detect the driver, I guess it just isn't supported in the newest one.  Probably should've tried it sooner.